# looping in background while running other statements c++

Tags: c++

I want to make a program which displays current time that ticks in background then is it possible to initialize  cin input processes while it is ticking?

Comment: It is possible. Please show your code for both sections (timer and cin).

Comment: MaximaDrive: use threads :)

Answer (score 0):

just for fun:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <ctime>

std::mutex more_lock;
std::string more_output;
void set_more_output(const std::string& more)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(more_lock);
    more_output = more;
}

std::string get_more_output()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(more_lock);
    return more_output;
}

std::atomic_bool running {true};
std::thread start_timer_runner()
{
    return std::thread([&]{
        while(running) {
            using namespace std::chrono;
            using namespace std::chrono_literals;
            auto now = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now());
            auto now_str = std::string(std::ctime(&now));
            now_str.pop_back(); // ctime adds new line
            std::cout << "\r" << now_str << " | " << get_more_output() << std::flush;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        }
    });
}

void parse_decimals()
{
    int x;
    set_more_output("please enter a decimal: ");
    while(std::cin >> x)
    {
        set_more_output("thanks! you entered " + std::to_string(x) + ", please enter a new decimal: ");
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto timer = start_timer_runner();
    parse_decimals();
    running = false;
    timer.join();
    std::cout << std::endl << "bye bye!" << std::endl;
}
```